# SSIS Move file from one domain to another

Tags: sql-server, ssis, move

I am trying to move a file via SSIS from one domain to another. SSIS is running in the SQL Server in Domain A. Clearly, when I move the file to a machine in Domain B, I get an error "Access to the path is denied". What is the cleanest way to solve for this?

thanks

Comment: The cleanest way is to make the domains trust each other. Otherwise you have to pre-authenticate with a hard coded login/password that is valid on that domain https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/61543654-351e-491d-a31b-c72809425fcb/copy-files-cross-domain?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: The domains trust each other. When i run this from SSIS editor everything is fine. When i deploy the package to SqL server and run it as an agent, i see this issue. How do I handle this?

Comment: When it runs under the agent it's running under a different windows account. What account does the job log say it is running under? Use a SQL Agent Proxy account to run it under an account that has access. Theoretically that should work but I'll do some googling

Comment: After you follow the steps above, if you're still having problems, make sure you use a URI ( `//server/path/folder/file.txt` ) to access a resource on a different server. You may need to enable file sharing, and you may need to grant access to SQL Agent or its proxy, if you use one.